# SystemVerilog changing port type from wire to logic gives error when usingn default_nettype none

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am converting my design from Verilog to SystemVerilog and by default I have `'default_nettype none` directive. Here is my design:

```
`default_nettype none

module my_design 
#(
parameter INPUT_WIDTH  = 16,
parameter OUTPUT_WIDTH = 2*INPUT_WIDTH
)
(
    input  wire signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  x_in,
    input  wire signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  y_in,
    output wire signed [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0]  z_out
);
```

Which compiles whithout any issue. However, when I change wire to logic as follow:

```
module my_design 
#(
parameter INPUT_WIDTH  = 16,
parameter OUTPUT_WIDTH = 2*INPUT_WIDTH
)
(
    input  logic signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  x_in,
    input  logic signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  y_in,
    output logic signed [OUTPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0]  z_out
);
```

I am getting the following error for all my port signals:

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1103] net type must be explicitly specified for 'x_in' 
when default_nettype is none
```

Which is very strange to me since I have explicitly decalred all the ports. I am using `Vivado Simulator 2018.2`. I am using the following command to compile the above codes:

```
xvlog --sv -f files.f
```

And files.f contains my design and test file only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input ports are implicitly `wire` net types with an implicit `logic` data type. SystemVerilog chose these defaults to be backward compatible with Verilog.

So your original Verilog input declaration was an explicit `wire` with an implicit `logic` data type. You changed it to an implicit `wire` nettype with an explicit `logic` data type.  But the result is functionally the same. You need to add back the `wire` keyword.

The following are all functionally equivalent:

```
 input signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  x_in, // implicit wire logic
 input logic signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  x_in, // implicit wire
 input wire signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  x_in, // implicit logic
 input wire logic signed [INPUT_WIDTH-1 : 0 ]  x_in, // explicit
```

Comment: Do you mean to change port from logic to wire? or `default_nettype from none to wire? because changing default_nettype to wire seems to be working as well.

Comment: If you change `default_nettype to wire, then you lose the typographical error checking.

Comment: @dave_59 Q1: Does it mean that we should keep `default_nettype none` and explicitly specify the net-type in the Verilog code (e.g., `input wire some_signal`)?, Q2: By typographical errors, do you mean spelling mistakes in the Verilog keywords? If so, won't Modelsim anyway detect such errors irrespective of the `default nettype` settings?

Comment: Keep `default_nettype none`. I mean typos in signal names, not keywords.